# Are questions about birth control/sex/contraception OK here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Questions about sex, birth control and contraception differs from biology I think. Are those appropriate here? or any other SO site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like most of the human health related questions, it depends on the context. If the question has to do with the biology/biochemistry underlying, for example, mechanisms of birth control ("how do birth control pills suppress ovulation?"), then it should be fine and on-topic here.

If the question veers into personal health recommendations or medical advice, then it's off-topic as defined in the FAQ.

Comment: Other StackExchange site for that type of question?

Comment: I doubt any SE site will accept medical advice. Too much liability. There is an area51 proposal for medicine: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45132/medicine